# Removing unused images (@2x or @3x) from ios bundle in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, optimization

I am trying to optimise my apps performance and added `@3x` and `@2x` suffixes to my images as per react-native guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

This obviously duplicates images, but I was under assumption that based on device only `@2x` or `@3x` images will be removed?

Right now my bundle just increased to extra 15mb in size and it seems that all of the images are used no matter what device I am testing on.

Is this expected or are there ways to improve it, so correct resolutions are used per device, but extra images are not bundled?

App size was tested through `TestFlight`, I'm not sure, but perhaps when downloaded from App Store these images are removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used `react-native-cli` then you can compile the project in `Xcode` IDE for the `iOS` folder. If this compiles successfully then follow the below steps,

You need to enable `bitcode` in your project's Build Settings to enable `App Thinning` feature.

The process to enable `Bitcode`:

- In the project build settings, make sure you have enabled All settings to be visible.
- The Build Options are the 4th section down. Select `Yes` for the `Enable Bitcode` option.

> The App Store and operating system optimize the installation of iOS, tvOS, and watchOS apps by tailoring app delivery to the capabilities of the user’s particular device, with minimal footprint. This optimization, called app thinning, lets you create apps that use the most device features, occupy minimum disk space, and accommodate future updates that can be applied by Apple. Faster downloads and more space for other apps and content provides a better user experience.
>
> Slicing (iOS, tvOS)
>   Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the executable architecture and resources that are needed for the target device. You continue to develop and upload full versions of your app to App Store Connect. The App Store will create and deliver different variants based on the devices your app supports. Use asset catalogs so that the App Store can select images, GPU resources, and other data appropriate for each device variant. When the user installs an app, a variant for the user’s device is downloaded and installed.
>
> Xcode simulates slicing during development so you can create and test variants locally. Xcode slices your app when you build and run your app on a device or in Simulator. When you create an archive, Xcode includes the full version of your app but allows you to export variants from the archive.
>
> Note: Sliced apps are supported on devices running 9.0 and later; otherwise, the App Store delivers universal apps to customers.

For more details about reducing the app size, please refer [Reducing the size of my App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html) [App Thinning](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdc5ce4f)

Comment: Thank you for extra info, this is actually how my project is set up now. I archived my app with XCode, my min ios target is set to 11.4, I'm using XCode 10.

When I upload app to app centre, there is an option to view `App Store Sizes`. For me all of these are the same, furthermore they are increased since adding `@2x` images in.

I opened related issue in react-native repo that has some further details (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22826)

Out of curiosity, did you actually manage to get this working? If so how would one test this properly pre App Store?

Comment: In TestFlight build, it can be tested it will show the bundle size in TestFlight app. You can observe different binary sizes in different devices.

Comment: Thats how I tested it, via TestFlight on iPhone XS and iPhone 5. Bundle sizes were the same. I double checked in `Settings` app as well. One caveat I didn't mention is that my images are stored alongside my js code in custom folder `assets/myImage@3x.png` and `assets/myImage@2x.png`, so they are not coming from `.xcassets`. Can this be the issue, i.e. does react-native cli copy my images to .xcassets or no?

Comment: Images should be there in `.xcassets` folder to make use of `App Slicing`, I don't think `react-native cli` copy does that automatically.

Comment: Thats my problem then. I used to have them in `.xcassets` before, but ran into memory management issues when I used them alongside react native, i.e. images loaded into memory and never offloaded. I'll dig around, thank you for your time :)

Comment: glad to help you @Ilja